# Confidence interval of a two-way election race

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

Consider a two-way election race between Ahmed and Amara to elect a new student council president at a Carleton University. Suppose that **500** students were randomly selected from the population of students. Among them, $237$ students said that they would vote for Ahmed. 
(a) Give a point estimate of the proportion of all students who will vote for Ahmed. 
(b) Estimate the proportion of all students who will vote for Ahmed with $97\%$ confidence.

My work:

I first found the mean: $237/500 = 0.474,$ and I know that the sample size is 500, but I'm not sure how to go about finding the confidence interval without the variance.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

While trying some more I got $0.474 + 2.96*\sqrt{0.474*0.526)/500},$ which equals $[0.4079,0.5401]$, but the answer says that the interval is $[0.426,0.522].$ Still not sure where I am going wrong!

Comment: I put some TeX symbols into your question to make it easier to read. Glad you found your way to the right answer. Maybe select 'edit' to have a look at the edits for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Found out where I was going wrong after my EDIT, used the wrong critical value for a **97%** confidence interval, should have been **2.170**, which results in the correct confidence interval.